# Is there a C compiler that targets the 8086?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, x86, x86-16

I have an 8086 CPU emulator. It emulates only 8086 instructions. I am searching now for a C compiler to target this emulator with. Is there any C compiler out there that can do this?

Also, having a usable libc and such is not important to me. The emulator uses custom(ie, non-PC) hardware and therefor any libc or even ctr0 would probably have to be rewritten anyway

Comment: Any 16-bit DOS compiler.

Comment: Sadly, yes, too many of them, and too many college professors making their students use them....

Comment: @R.. @Hans many of the compilers I've seen target higher up than the 8086, usually they go up to 8186 and 8286 opcodes.

Comment: @Earlz What about MS C compiler for DOS (QuickC) (as far as I remember, MS-DOS (or at least some core parts of it) never relied on anything above 8086, so..) One link I found (which reports tech problems at the moment) is http://vetusware.com/download/QuickC%202.51/?id=3503, and there're others too. Hope that will help you and (if too late) anyone interested.

Comment: @mlv thanks but I was looking more for a modernish compiler supporting at least C89

Comment: Microsoft's [QuickC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickC) may do it. But its so old, you may not be able to find it anywhere. I have the 1.44 floppy disks somewhere (there are 5 of them, IIRC). And Microsoft's [MASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler) will surely do it if you don't mind some ASM.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227762/looking-for-16-bit-x86-compiler

Answer (score 12):

**bcc - Bruce's C compiler**

From [*bcc(1) - Linux man page*](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bcc):

> Description
>
> Bcc is a simple C compiler that produces 8086 assembler, in addition compiler compile time options allow 80386 or 6809 versions. The compiler understands traditional K&R C with just the restriction that bit fields are mapped to one of the other integer types.
>
> The default operation is to produce an 8086 executable called a.out from the source file.

**Open Watcom**

From the description of compiler option / 80x86 run-time convention **0** in [*Open Watcom C/C++ User’s Guide*](http://www.openwatcom.org/ftp/manuals/current/cguide.pdf) (PDF link):

> (16-bit only) The compiler will make use of only 8086 instructions in the generated object code.  This is the
>   default.  The resulting code will run on 8086 and all upward compatible processors.  The macro __SW_0
>   will be predefined if "0" is selected

Answer (score 7):

- [Open Watcom](http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Detailed_Contents#A_Wide_Range_of_Host_and_Target_Platforms)
- [Digital Mars](http://www.digitalmars.com/features.html)
- [bcc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bcc)

Comment: Are you sure Digital Mars will generate binaries using only 8086 opcodes?

Comment: @Earlz: Digital Mars can target the 8088, which is the same instruction set as the 8086: http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/sc.html#dash023456

Comment: Another compiler that might be worth trying (I'm not sure though - it needs an MS-DOS environment to run in): Turbo C++ 2: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20841

Comment: @Mich no thanks, I'll stay as far away from Turbo C as possible lol

Answer (score 2):

[Free Pascal](https://www.freepascal.org/) can also produce [16 bit 8086 executable](https://wiki.freepascal.org/DOS). It is not a native compiler, you have to compile it on your contemporary 32/64 bit machine and then copy the executable to your 16 bit IBM 51XX or clone.

[gcc-ia16](https://github.com/tkchia/gcc-ia16) TK Chia's GCC compiler targeted for 8086. It is actively developed. It is used to compile a huge 16 bit project such as [ELKS Linux](https://github.com/jbruchon/elks) and all its applications. It is also not a native compiler.