# Looking for 16-bit c compiler for x86

Tags: compiler-construction, x86, real-mode

I am working on porting uc/OS-II from DOS to x86 (real mode). I need:

1. A compiler to generate real mode 16-bit x86 assembly
2. An assembler to assemble the generated assembly into an object file
3. A linker to link the object files together and output an executable (raw binary, COFF, PE, or 
   ELF formats are fine)
4. A standard library without invoking any DOS services (`int 21h`), only depend on BIOS service.

I am wondering whether there is any tool-chain could do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [FreeDOS](http://www.freedos.org) project. They have [developer tools](http://www.freedos.org/software/?cat=devel) that include compilers, assemblers, and linkers. You'll probably have to modify the standard library, though, so that it uses BIOS calls rather than int 21h.

Answer (score 1):

16-bit compilers?   Several of them are mentioned here:

[Is there a C compiler that targets the 8086?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493035/is-there-a-c-compiler-that-targets-the-8086)

Generally they are used for academic exercises, so if u target at educational institution you can find lots of examples too:

http://www.google.com.sg/search?q=site%3Aedu+C+compiler+8086

Answer (score 1):

At a former job we had a project that was based on uc/OS running on a real-mode x86 platform. We used TopSpeed C rather than the more well-known Borland or Microsoft compilers, because TopSpeed C was the only one of the set available and viable at the time that got `volatile` right. Which you dearly need when building uc/OS. Both Turbo C and Microsoft C (and I think its QuickC too) miscompiled accesses to `volatile` variables - typically caching values in registers and similar breakage.

You'd have a hard time getting hold of TopSpeed C, though. And its assembler syntax is... unique. (I think it's based on Modula-2 or something; it ends up being very unlike MASM/TASM/nasm with which you may be 100 times more familiar.)

Answer (score -1):

Check out any bootloader project, such as GRUB.  It should be readily apparent that they also need everything you mentioned.

Comment: Hello, as far as I know. Grub is running under protected mode on x86

Comment: @user639642: It starts in real mode, and I think it later sets up protected mode, but it definitely starts out in real mode (when the BIOS transfers control to the MBR).

Comment: I have take a look of grub2 and build it. It use gcc to compile. As far as I know, there isn't 16-bit real mode x86 assembly support in gcc. I guess the real mode part of grub2 is written in assembly. C is used under protected mode.