# nasm/ld "relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16"

Tags: assembly, nasm, ld, x86-16, bootloader

Assembly:

```
[BITS 16]

global _start

_start:
    mov ax, 0x07C0
    mov ds, ax

    mov si, hw
    call print_string
    jmp $

print_string:
    mov ah, 0x0E
.char:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je .exit
    int 0x10
    jmp .char
.exit: ret

times 0x100-($-$$) db 0

hw: db "Hello, World!", 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

Assembling this with:

```
$ nasm file.asm -felf -o file.o
```

And then linking it with:

```
$ ld -melf_i386 -o file.bin file.o --oformat binary
```

Gives the following error:

```
file.asm:(.text+0x6): relocation truncated to fit: R_386_16 against `.text'
```

After fiddling with the code a bit, i figured out that changing `mov si, hw` to `mov si, 0x100` works fine. But then what's the point of labels?

My guess is that ld can't generate 16 bits binary files, so it replaces `hw` with a 32 bit address instead of a 16 bit address. And then it complains because my program tries to put a 32 bit value into a 16 bit register.

Is there some argument i can pass to nasm/ld to make this work?

---

**EDIT:**

elf doesn't support 16 bit, the only output format nasm supports wich actually states it supports 16 bit in `nasm -hf` is .obj, but i can't find a linker for it.

---

NASM Manual:

> The ELF32 specification doesn't provide relocations for 8- and 16-bit values, but the GNU ld linker adds these as an extension. NASM can generate GNU-compatible relocations, to allow 16-bit code to be linked as ELF using GNU ld. If NASM is used with the -w+gnu-elf-extensions option, a warning is issued when one of these relocations is generated.

Adding `-w+gnu-elf-extensions` does indeed show a warning, but ld still gives the same error.

Comment: You are using `elf` format which is 32 bit. Since you apparently want a raw boot sector, use `nasm -f bin` and do not link.

Comment: @Jester Yes, for the simple example i provided in the question that does work. But my full code is a lot more complicated than this, and would really benefit from being linked.

Comment: Then try to find a 16 bit linker and use some 16 bit object format.

Comment: @Jester The only output format nasm supports wich actually states it supports 16 bit according to `nasm -hf` is .obj, but i can't find a linker for it.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a boot sector.  You wouldn't *want* to link it.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer As i stated previously "my full code is a lot more complicated than this, and would really benefit from being linked". The example i gave is indeed a boot sector. It's just an example that produces the same error as my main code.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer : When using NASM to generate DWARF debug information (for remote QEMU debugging on a bootloader), I'll use NASM to output an ELF object, use the linker to output an ELF image, and then use OBJCOPY to convert the elf image to a flat binary. This allows me to run a flat binary on a remote target like QEMU, and use the local ELF image for its symbol table. Much easier to set break points etc. I discuss one such way in this [Stackoverflow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32960272/3857942)

Comment: Ok. I am pretty curious as to how linking will be useful without an is running :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer : The extra linking phase allows you to generate ELF images with debug information, and then allows you to use Objcopy that to generate the target binary file. The extra step produces an ELF image of the final binary that can be used for debug symbols. If you assemble straight to binary (with `nasm -f bin`) you lose the ability to create useful debug information. In my use cases I'm not actually using the ELF files to run, I'm using them for the extra info they can contain, and that is very useful for me when remote debugging my OS/bootloader with remote QEMU debugging with GDB.

Comment: An example of using LD for that purpose (followed by Objcopy) can be found in this answer that shows how one can remote debug with GDB and QEMU with the intermediate ELF image created by the linker. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32960272/3857942

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all I recommend you consider using an [i686 ELF Cross compiler](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) to avoid some gotchyas that can later bite you as you develop your kernel.

---

### Using NASM with the -f bin output option

Nothing prevents you from using *ELF* as the object file type with *NASM*, but it is often simpler to use the `-f bin` option that generates a fully resolved flat binary file that needs no fixups. It can be used as a boot sector without any linking step. The down side is that all the code has to be in the same. External assembler statement can be included with the `%include` directive, similar to *C*'s `include` directive.

For this to work you have to place the origin point in the assembler file so that *NASM* knows what the base offset (origin point) is needed for generating absolute addresses (for labels etc). You would modify your assembly code and add this at the top:

```
[ORG 0x0000]
```

This only applies when using `-f bin` output option, this directive will throw an error for other output types like `-f elf`. In this case we use 0x0000 because the segment your code assumes is 0x07c0 which is moved into *DS*. 0x07c0:0x0000 maps to physical address (0x07c0<<4)+0x0000 = 0x07c00 which is where our bootloader will be loaded into memory.

If you don't specify `[org 0x0000]`, then org = 0x0000 is the default when using the `-f bin` output option, so it isn't actually necessary to specify it. It just makes it much clearer to a reader by using it explicitly.

In order assemble this into a binary file you could do:

```
nasm file.asm -fbin -o file.bin
```

This would output a flat binary file called `file.bin` assembled from `file.asm`.No linking step is needed.

---

### Using NASM with the -f elf output option

In your example you are using *ELF*. There may be a couple reasons for doing it this way. Your generated binary file may be the combination of multiple object (`.o`) files, or you may wish to generate debug symbols to be used with a debugger like *GDB*. Whatever your reason this can be done using these commands:

```
nasm file.asm -felf -o file.o
ld -melf_i386 -Ttext 0x0 -o file.bin file.o --oformat binary
```

`-Ttext 0x0` would be the origin point that matches your code. 0x0000 in this case is the same value you would have used with the `ORG` directive had you used *NASM* with the `-f bin` output option. If you had written your code to assume an offset of 0x7c00 with code like:

```
xor ax, ax     ; AX = 0
mov ds, ax     ; DS = 0
```

Then the *TEXT* segment would have to be specified with:

```
ld -melf_i386 -Ttext 0x7c00 -o file.bin file.o --oformat binary
```

---

Your question may be: why do we need to explicitly set a value for the base of the *TEXT* segment? The reason is that the the default for *LD* is dependent on the the OS you are targeting (usually for the platform you are currently running on). If you are on Linux, by default *LD* will attempt to create output for Linux. On Linux the default for the start of the *TEXT* segment is usually `0x08048000` when specifying `-m elf_i386`. This is of course a 32-bit value.

Any place an absolute address was needed it would attempt to add `0x08048000` (or potentially some other large address) to it. So an instruction like this:

```
mov si, hw
```

Would attempt to move the address of `hw` into the 16-bit register *SI*. The linker would have attempted to resolve this to 0x08048000 + offset of `hw` when creating the flat binary output file. Because you have a 32-bit value being used in an instruction that only takes a 16-bit value, you will get a warning/error. *LD* will truncate the 32-bit value to 16-bit, unfortunately that would likely produce an incorrect 16-bit address.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: [Looking for 16-bit x86 compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227762/looking-for-16-bit-x86-compiler)

> something I learned the hard way;
>   -Ttext 0x0
>   is critical, otherwise the .text segment is pushed outside of 16bit addressing range (don't ask me why)